# Prometheus is reading metrics from wrong target

Tags: prometheus

i recently encountered a problem with my Prometheus setup. 
Some time ago i configured Prometheus to scrape metrics from an WebApi (let say) on target: someHost001:443 and otherHost:443. My web api is exposing the summary metric where i measure requests times.

This was my configuration:

```
...
- job_name: "someJob"
tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
scheme: https
metrics_path: 'api/metrics'
bearer_token: 'token_string'
static_configs:
  - targets: ['someHost001:443', 'otherHost001:443']
...
```

Everything worked fine and the life was awesome, until after ~3-4 weeks later i added a third target: 'someHost002:443' to the job.

What i expected to see is a new data series with instance label equal to 'someHost002:433'. What i also expected to see is that the new data series will store api calls metrics from the new webapi instance on new host.

Indeed prometheus created new time series, however it seams that its reading the data not from someHost002:443/api/metrics but form someHost001:443/api/metrics.

I did some tests to narrow down the issue and did notice some interesting facts:

1. When i take down the someHost002 instance - prometheus will recognize that the instance is down and no new metric are read to this time series.
2. When i make api calls only to someHost002 prometheus don't reads them (because it is reading metric only from someHost001)

Almost from the beginning of my setup prometheus has scraped metrics from otherHost001 without any problems.

I also have created a new job that reads metrics only form the new host, and still it seams that prometheus is reading them from wrong instance.

Did somebody experienced similar problems ? It is possible that this is a Prometheus bug?

Comment: There's definitely something weird going on there. Can you confirm that DNS is working as expected, and that there's no proxies in the way?

Comment: Nope, no problems with DNS and proxies. In fact i have another job scraping other metrics from different WebApi on the someHost002.

Comment: What version of Prometheus is this?

Comment: Prometheus version: 
Version 1.7.1
Revision 3afb3fffa3a29c3de865e1172fb740442e9d0133
Branch master
BuildUser root@0aa1b7fc430d
BuildDate 20170612-11:44:05
GoVersion go1.8.3

Comment: I experienced a similar problem and I am investigating it, did you ever conclude what the root cause was?

Comment: I was able to root cause it to an issue with DNS and multiple interfaces. I fixed it by making each host have one interface and using the dns service discovery in prometheus as opposed to implicitly relying on it.